# Understanding Bernoulli Trials, Bayesian Setting

Tags: machine-learning, beginner, bayesian

I am required to complete a project on ML applications. I guess there is a lot of statistics in ML, not helpful for a non-maths background.

I am getting too bogged down by notations. There are too many notations.

**I am trying to read about what Bernoulli trials are and I can't relate to it.**

**What is a Bayesian setting and why is Bayesian thing everywhere?** What makes it such an omnipotent distribution?

Are there any theorems/theories that I must know ? Any book/notes/resources where I could learn about these stuff in a relatable way (I have very little maths background, but I can learn)?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I edited the question to make it more clear. Feel free t roll it back if needed :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is a Bayesian setting and why is Bayesian thing everywhere?

In very simple terms:

> Bayesian is a statistical setting, where the likelihood of an event
>   happening (called the posterior) depends on the prior trials or
>   observations (called the prior(s)).

Bayesian networks is an extension of the above, forming a chain or a network of inferencing.

> Are there any theorems/theories that I must know?

For understanding the Bayesian paradigm, you need to know the Bayesian theorem/relation, which is basically:

$$P(\theta|d) = \dfrac{P(d|\theta)P(\theta)}{P(d)}.$$

> Any book/notes/resources where I could learn about these stuff in a
>   relatable way (I have very little maths background, but I can learn)?

I would highly recommend ["Doing Bayesian Analysis" by John Krushke](http://store.elsevier.com/Doing-Bayesian-Data-Analysis/John-Kruschke/isbn-9780124059160/)

Comment: Thanks, that was very helpful. Any more resources you could add, in general towards maths based analysis of problems in ML. Thanks again.